# Drawing transitive diagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I am very new to Tikz. How to draw rounded arrows and nodes without rectangular boundary. I want to draw something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite possible to draw curved paths.  There are several ways to do this:

You can use the `to` directive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0)    {A};
  \node (B) at (0,-2in) {B};

  \draw[arrows=->] (A) to[out=-45,in=45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `controls`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0)    {A};
  \node (B) at (0,-2in) {B};

  \draw[arrows=->] (A) .. controls (2,-0.5in) and (2,-1.5in) .. (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Here's something that starts to look like the image you posted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\myVpos{0}
\def\myVadj{1}

\def\myToneList{1/call/m1,
                2/lock/l,
                3/write/x,
                4/unlock/l,
                5/ret/m1,
                11/call/m3,
                12/lock/l,
                13/read/x,
                14/unlock/l,
                15/ert/m3}
\def\myTtwoList{6/call/m2,
                7/lock/l,
                8/write/x,
                9/ret/l,
                10/ret/m2}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% T1 list
  \foreach \x/\y/\z
       [evaluate={\myVpos=\myVpos+\myVadj}, 
        remember=\myVpos as \myVpos (initially 0)
        ] 
       in \myToneList
  {
    \node (t1_\x) at (0,-\myVpos)           {{\ttfamily\y(t1,\z)}};
    \node         at ($(t1_\x)+(-1.5cm,0)$) {\x};
  }

  \xdef\myCurrentPos{t1_1}
  \foreach \x/\y/\z in \myToneList 
  { 
    \edef\myTest{t1_\x}
    \ifx\myCurrentPos\myTest\else\draw[arrows=->] (\myCurrentPos.south) to (t1_\x.north) ; \fi
    \xdef\myCurrentPos{t1_\x}
  }

  %%\draw[arrows=->,dashed] (t1_4.east) to[out=-10,in=10] node[right] {?} (t1_12.east);
  \draw[arrows=->,dashed] 
    (t1_4.east) 
    .. 
    controls ($(t1_4)+(-10:3.5cm)$) 
             and 
             ($(t1_12)+(10:5.5cm)$) 
    .. 
    node[right,pos=0.65] {?} 
    (t1_12.east);

  %% T2 list
  \foreach \x/\y/\z
       [evaluate={\myVpos=\myVpos+\myVadj}, 
        remember=\myVpos as \myVpos (initially 0)
        ] 
       in \myTtwoList
  {
    \node (t2_\x) at (6,-\myVpos)          {{\ttfamily\y(t2,\z)}};
    \node         at ($(t2_\x)+(1.5cm,0)$) {\x};
  }

  \xdef\myCurrentPos{t2_6}
  \foreach \x/\y/\z in \myTtwoList 
  { 
    \edef\myTest{t2_\x}
    \ifx\myCurrentPos\myTest\else\draw[arrows=->] (\myCurrentPos.south) to (t2_\x.north) ; \fi
    \xdef\myCurrentPos{t2_\x}
  }

  %% across T1 and T2
  \draw[arrows=->] (t1_4.north east) -- (t2_7.south west);
  \draw[arrows=->] (t2_9.south west) -- (t1_12.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) But it is giving me "its giving me \z does not match its definition in (t1_12.east) error " error. What should I do?

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure what to tell.  Perhaps you've got a misplaced bracket?  I'm not able to duplicate your error message.  There is no `\z` in the line where I call `(t1_12.east)`.